# c# IList element via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a reflected property which is an IList. I have managed to use reflection to get the IList, but now I want to get a list of the properties of one of the elements (any element will do). The attempts I've made so far have failed.

The way I'd handled this before was to use .GetType().GetProperties, but if I try this:

```
 PropertyInfo[] pi = i[0].GetType().GetProperties();
```

It doesn't return anything. I know that the item in the list has some properties, but I just can't seem to get a list of them.

'i' is the IList and, if I run the program, it will tell me that it has one object (an instance of an NPC class). It will also give me the details using the intellisense. I just can't seem to get to these details using reflection. Please help!

Comment: Properties are public? Please show a few more lines and the NPC class!

Comment: It's IList or IList<T>? Doesn't make a difference to the answer i just wondered. To get the properties do you not need to use BindingFlags?

Comment: Sorry, @Fruchtzwerg, you are right! Some of the properties weren't public. Thanks a lot!